# NativeScript, css specific for devices

Tags: css, nativescript

How do I make css for specific devices in NativeScript? For example this is working great in iPhone X, XS, XS MAX. But it do not the rest of devices.

```
.page {
     margin: -44 0 44 0;
}
```

Is there a way to make css specific for a device or a group of devices

Answer (score 0):

Try the `nativescript-platform-css` plugin, that helps you write platform, device, screen size, and orientation specific css styles.

```
tns plugin add nativescript-platform-css
```

Comment: Can you show me little more how to apply the css. For example I am trying to write like this: .iphoneX .page {color: red}. But nothing happens

Comment: Please go through the [documentation](https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-platform-css/blob/master/src/README.md) in the plugin, if you still have questions from that, let's know.

Comment: Please be more specific, what you couldn't get work. For iPhoneX all you have to do was just use `.iphonex` class as mentioned [here](https://github.com/NathanaelA/nativescript-platform-css/blob/master/src/README.md#enhanced-modes). If you can't get it work, please submit a sample project where the issue can be reproduced.